# Joi - make everything required by default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I'm building out a Node/Express API and using Joi for validation. It's a great package and has been incredibly useful. However, we're getting tired of doing things like:

```
const mySchema = joi.object({
    thing1: joi.string().required(),
    thing2: joi.string().required(),
    thing3: joi.string().required(),
    thing4: joi.string().required(),
    thing5: joi.string().required(),
}).required();
```

We'd like *everything* to be required by default, and manually call `.optional` to override that. In fact this seems a sensible default - but leaving that aside for now.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: why not build a wrapper function around this ?

Comment: @madalinivascu Because it seems like something that should be achievable out of the box with a validation library...

Answer (score 22):

You can use `presence` option to make fields required by default. Example:

```js
const mySchema = joi.object({
    thing1: joi.string(),
    thing2: joi.string(),
    thing3: joi.string(),
    thing4: joi.string(),
    thing5: joi.string(),
}).options({ presence: 'required' }).required();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and should be marked as correct.

Comment: for reference, here's the docs

https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.8.3#anyprefsoptions---aliases-preferences-options

Answer (score 0):

There does not exist a standard way of making every key required, but there are workarounds.
One of the workaround can be usage of `.requiredKeys()` and `.optionalKeys()` on `Joi.object()`

Have a look at [`.describe()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v15.0.1/API.md#describeschema) function,
It returns an object which has a key `flags`.
When a key is marked as 'optional', we get `flags.presence = 'optional'`

Using that information, you can call `.describe()` on each key and prepare two arrays of `requiredKey` and `optionalKeys`

And then, you can pass those arrays to `.requiredKeys()` and `.optionalKeys()` respectively.

For example:
Say you define your joi schema as:

```
const joiSchemaKeys = {
    thing1: Joi.string(),
    thing2: Joi.string().optional(),
    thing3: Joi.string(),
    thing4: Joi.string(),
    thing5: Joi.string().required()
};
```

You can then prepare two arrays `optionalKeys` and `requiredKeys` using this:

```
const initialKeyInformation = {
    requiredKeys: [],
    optionalKeys: []
};

const prepareKeysInformation = keys =>
    Object.keys(keys).reduce((accumulated, aKey) => {
        const description = keys[aKey].describe();
        const isMarkedOptional =
            description.flags &&
            description.flags.presence &&
            description.flags.presence === "optional";

        if (isMarkedOptional) {
            console.log(`"${aKey}" is marked optional`);
            accumulated.optionalKeys.push(aKey);
        } else {
            console.log(`"${aKey}" is not marked, making it required`);
            accumulated.requiredKeys.push(aKey);
        }
        return accumulated;
    }, initialKeyInformation);

const { optionalKeys, requiredKeys } = prepareKeysInformation(joiSchemaKeys);
```

Once that is done, you can prepare your joi schema like:

```
const schema = Joi.object()
    .keys(joiSchemaKeys)
    .requiredKeys(requiredKeys)
    .optionalKeys(optionalKeys);
```

So this way, you will make every key required unless specified otherwise.